# How django cache RawQuerySet

Tags: python, django

I meet a memory problem when execute huge RawQuerySet in Django. And gc.collect() could not works to release the memory after query. And I check the code in Django. Find this code snippet https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.6.x/django/db/models/query.py#L1391-L1396:

```
    # Cache some things for performance reasons outside the loop.
    db = self.db
    compiler = connections[db].ops.compiler('SQLCompiler')(
        self.query, connections[db], db
    )
    need_resolv_columns = hasattr(compiler, 'resolve_columns')
```

But I could not understand how django cache it. Seem it just get the columns here. My questions how django cache it in this code snippet? Thank you very much.

Update:

Thank you for @bruno-desthuilliers help, but I find the true reason is MySQLdb.Cursor. https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/blob/master/MySQLdb/cursors.py#L533-L534 Django only could use StoreResultCursor and it fetch all result and store it to memory. And as @bruno-desthuilliers says, the comment is wrong here. Here is not have any cache operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "caching" term is a bit confusing here. There's no real "caching" involved here, only the creation of local variables to store loop invariants as to avoid any attribute lookup, call or whatever for these names in the following code.

FWIW, there's not much in term of "caching" in `RawQuerySet`... Neither [RawQuerySet.**iter**()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.6.x/django/db/models/query.py#L1382) - which only iterates over the `RawQuery`, processes the raw results and yield them - nor [`RawQuery.__iter__()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.6.x/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L70) - are caching anything. At this point the only potential cause of high memory consumption is the [conditional call to `list(self.cursor)`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.6.x/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L77) which is not a cache but can indeed eat quite some space on a huge dataset.

As a side note: [Python processes tend to keep most of the already allocated memory](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesnt-python-release-the-memory-when-i-delete-a-large-object.htm).

Comment: Hi, thank your for your reply very much. "in the following code." Could you explain more about this? In the following code, it seems only iterate the query and yield the result. Don't contains store cache operation.

Comment: Yes that's what I said: **there's no caching involved here** (in the sense of a db cache or whatsoever). What is "cached" (in the sense of "bound to local names") are a couple attributes etc that are frequently used in the function, to avoid the cost of attribute lookup in the loops.

Comment: But as you say, if "there's no caching involved here ". Why I after call iterate the RawQuerySet. The memory increase to 2 GB from 92MB. And I call gc.collect() also could not release memory.

Comment: @haosdent I'm specifically talking about the part of the code you referenced and the "# Cache some things for performance reasons outside the loop." comment. What I mean is that the "cache" word in the comment is misleading and has nothing to do with the caching of the queryset's results

Comment: Thank you very much for your detail answer. Let me try some way to skip this trap

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I find the true reason is MySQLdb.Cursor. https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/blob/master/MySQLdb/cursors.py#L533-L534 It fetch all result and store it to memory.